# Setting up myCustomMethod() acting like onCreate()... in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to programming, and i don't even know how to call what i want to do:

basically i have some values stored in my MainActivity.class, and other classes are able to edit those values.

I would like to update my Fragment UI with those new values each time at least one of them changes.

So the cleanest way to do this IMO was to make a

```
@Override
onValuesChanged(){
//do something
}
```

alongside onCreate(), onResume(), ...

is there a way to accomplish what i want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a very standard pattern you could just make your values `private` and define `setter` functions and make sure that in each `setter` you call your `updateUI()` function.

```
public void setMyValue(final int myValue) {
   this.myValue = myValue;
   this.updateUI();
}
```